# Changing color of a line in a multiline textbox if the line begins with a specific character?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

So long story short, I'd like to make it so that if a line in a multiline textbox beings with 
'!' it makes the line color red. Otherwise, it remains black.

Sounds simple with an if statement, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly to do. Is such a thing possible?

I'm using C#.
*To clarify, I would like it to do it automatically, not needing a button to be pressed.

Comment: Probably with a RichTextBox it is easier.

Comment: You need a `RichTextBox`, AFAIK `TextBox` doesn't supports multiple colors.

Comment: I've looked into RichTextBox, and I'm aware of it's ability to change a line's colors, but I'm not sure how I would go about actually 'scanning' the line for the '!'.

Comment: `RichTextBox` has `Find` method, `Lines` property, and `SelectionColor` property. Work on it, come back when you're struck. Thank you..

Comment: Alright, sounds easy enough then. Guess I didn't look into it enough, thanks!

Comment: You could even go about using `.Split()` property.

Answer (score 7):

`TextBox` does not support what you need, you should use `RichTextBox`.

Anyway the simplest way to do what you want with a RichTextBox is to take the text out of it, clear the contents and add the text back with your desired formatting:

```
private void FormatTextBox(RichTextBox richText, string p, 
            Color textColor, Color highColor)
{
    string[] lines = richText.Lines;
    richText.Text = "";

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        richText.SelectionColor = line.StartsWith(p) ? highColor : textColor;
        richText.AppendText(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormatTextBox(richTextBox1, "!", Color.Black, Color.Red);
}
```

Of course this can be improved with using selection or adding the same-formatted text in a single `AppendText` call, but as I said this is simple.

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for, been a bit stumped for the past 30 minutes but this is a push in the right direction for me. Thanks for the help fellas.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble trying to make it automatically do this without the need of pressing a button. I ran into something like this when I made a linecounter label, so I ended up wiring it to a timer, but this is a bit more complicated than that. Any tips?

Comment: The solution depends on the amount of text in your RichTextBox

Answer (score 2):

Might not be perfect, but it does the job:

```
        string charac = "!";
        int lengthAll = richTextBox1.TextLength;
        int location = richTextBox1.Find(charac);
        int length = lengthAll-location;
        richTextBox1.Select(location, length);
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

In the `RichTextBox` I just wrote some simple line with a ! in it.